# What is the correct name and significance of EAV table pivot?

Tags: table, eav

I've been forced to use a very uncomfortable structure for a table. After trying to up similar examples, I've discovered the EAV, which seems almost like a pivot of said structure. The attribute order is not set in stone (except that there are no new attributes after a NULL column). For the max amount of attributes N, there are 2*N columns in pairs of Attribute_Name - Attribute value.

EAV example:

```
ID| Entity  | Attribute  | Value
__________________________________
1 | Entity1 | Attribute1 | Value1
2 | Entity2 | Attribute1 | Value2
3 | Entity2 | Attribute2 | Value3
4 | Entity2 | Attribute3 | Value4
5 | Entity3 | Attribute1 | Value5
6 | Entity3 | Attribute2 | Value6
```

Example of my table:

```
Entity  | A_Name1    | A_Value1 | A_Name2       | A_Value2 | A_Name3       | A_Value3
______________________________________________________________________________________
Entity1 | Attribute1 | Value1   | NULL          | NULL     | NULL          | NULL
Entity2 | Attribute2 | Value3   | Attribute1    | Value2   | Attribute3    | Value4
Entity3 | Attribute2 | Value6   | Attribute1    | Value5   |  NULL         | NULL
```

Should this be considered separate from EAV structure? Is there any classification for this kind of table structure, or is it one of a kind? Basically, I want to learn as much as possible about it and ways to work around it.

EDIT: Forgot to mention -- the Attribute names might also repeat like this:

```
Entity  | A_Name1    | A_Value1 | A_Name2       | A_Value2 | A_Name3       | A_Value3
______________________________________________________________________________________
Entity1 | Attribute1 | Value1   | NULL          | NULL     | NULL          | NULL
Entity2 | Attribute2 | Value3   | Attribute1    | Value2   | Attribute2    | Value4
Entity3 | Attribute2 | Value6   | Attribute1    | Value5   |  NULL         | NULL
```

Comment: *What* are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to find ways to make working with the table data and performing queries more comfortable.

Comment: Both of these structure are very bad anti-patterns, see http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back where both the EAV and numbered columns anti-patterns are listed.

Comment: See slides 14 & 15 on avoiding "numbers" in column names, while the coverage on EAV starts at slide 16.

Comment: EAV looks like heaven when one has to deal with this design :)

Comment: Joe Celko [here](http://joecelkothesqlapprentice.blogspot.ie/2006/06/changing-columns-of-select-statement.html) says that anyone coming across this design should "Find the moron that did this to you and kill him". No room for ambiguity there! His favoured synonym for EAV is MUCK (massively unified code key) for obvious reasons! Change it if you can.

Answer (score 1):

The process of pivoting data is often called transposition, as it is similar to the matrix operation of that name in mathematics (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose), though that isn't really what you are doing in your example.

In your output you *still have the EAV pattern* but stored less efficiently. The columns "Entity, A_Name1, A_Value1" is one attribute in the EAV pattern, "Entity, A_Name2, A_Value2" is another, and so forth. Each of your value columns could contain a range of probably unrelated attribute values so you are not in any sort of normal form and reporting is likely to be even more difficult than the original layout.

A proper transposition in this case would be:

```
Entity  | Attribute1 | Attribute2 | Attribute2 
----------------------------------------------
Entity1 | Value1     | NULL       | NULL       
Entity2 | Value2     | Value3     | Value4     
Entity3 | Value5     | Value6     | NULL
```

This way each column contains data for only one attribute.